# Can I increase cooking time of bread to make it less gooey?

Tags: baking, bread, gluten-free

I've been experimenting with gluten-free baking (due to Celiac, not because I think it will make me skinny). I've made great cakes and cookies, but recently tried to make rolls. In the process I've discovered how to make waffles and muffins, completely by accident. Today while "playing around" with my muffin recipe, hoping to make delicious oat bran muffins, I noticed that the insides didn't quite get done. Eventually they did sort of solidify.

So, what does any of this have to do with bread? Well, for some reason the "muffins" turned out instead to be bread. I don't mean "bread-like" I mean "bread" except in muffin tins. So, using this exact recipe I should be able make bread, but I'm worried about the bread not getting done all the way through since the cross section in a bread pan (which I'd have to buy) is larger than the muffin tins I was using.

My thought on how to "solve" this problem would be to lower the temperature a bit, and then extend the cooking time. The current muffins were cooked for about 30 minutes at 375 °F. I was thinking maybe 325 °F for 40?

Comment: It's very hard to answer questions like this without a recipe, could you post yours?

Comment: I actually considered posting the recipe, but decided against it to keep the question general, and any replies focused on my question instead of the recipe. From my experience with on-line communities I'm more likely to get my recipe picked over and told how idiotic it is, leaving my question completely unaddressed – can a recipe with the general description can be cooked more evenly by extending the cooking time and lowering the temperature?

I'm sorry if this is insufficient, but I'm not in the mood for being trolled, which is what seems to happen so frequently. I truly am sorry.

Comment: If there is some piece of information in specific that might help I can give that. I've just had a lot of exposure lately to toxic communities and am extra guarded right now.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, no I don't think you can.

I've had bread which has turned out sticky, gooey, or doughy in the center.  Usually, when we see this, we stick it back in to bake longer - there's a difference between under-baked and gooey, though it can be hard to tell at a glance.  Also usually, this doesn't work to make the center of gooey bread less so (except by drying out the whole loaf, which is not much of an improvement).  Gooey-in-the-center bread is (for me) often caused by other texture problems, often not rising enough, not holding its crumb, being dense as well as gooey.

If your bread is under-cooked, then lower and slower cooking will help in that it lets the center cook longer without overdoing the crust. If that is the primary problem, your solution should help - though you should perhaps try baking to internal temperature or looking for physical markers of done-ness  (like a hollow sound on tapping) instead of relying on baking time alone.  I should note there is some difference in texture depending on when the loaf is cut into (the release of steam and temperature, see questions [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/why-should-i-let-bread-cool-before-slicing-and-eating?s=1%7C0.5320) and [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13332/why-does-bread-taste-raw-if-you-stop-baking-it-and-continue-after-it-has-cooled)).  An under-baked loaf which has been cut into to be found gooey will likely not improve as much from further baking as compared to the same loaf cooked straight through, and a loaf which has been allowed to finish cooling before cutting will be dryer and sturdier than one cut into while still warm.

The sorts of things which usually do help gooey bread, or perhaps I mean the sorts of things whose lacking usually causes gooey-ness, includes using enough and strong enough leavening, making sure the dough is strong enough, with enough binders, to hold the air bubbles and let it rise well, and maybe trying a flatter, wider loaf (less pressure from the weight of the dough helps the dough keep its rise), or just smaller ones for quicker cooking to help set the crumb before the leavening is exhausted.

Comment: Thank you. That pretty much answered my question. Thing with this gooey bread was that the texture was other wise spot on and even the gooey parts had bubbles. It was weird. There was no lack of structure what so ever anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I bake a lot of sourdough bread, and I find that the higher the hydration percentage (the ratio of water to flour) the "gooier" the bread. You might want to try using less water in your recipe.

Comment: I've found that the amount of water is the number one means of controlling how much my gluten-free baked goods rise. It isn't that it makes them rise faster, it determines how much they will rise given any amount of time. I have no idea why, but that's how it is. I had to learn this that hard way. Thanks though. :D

Comment: I tried it out again today. I think this IS the issue. There were plenty of bubbles, so I think I'll add a bit more flour next time. Or rather, add coconut flour (just a bit). My bread sank in the middle as soon as I took it out. The typical cause, or so I've read, for this is too much liquid. Also, it had rather large bubbles, so I'm not too worried about it rising if I add a bit more flour.